# XPath : Select Text After

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I am unable to construct an XPath expression to scrape the text between the `<br>` tags. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

**Webpage:**

```
<hr>
<center>
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.html" target="_blank">Description</a>
</center>
<br>
SEC 10 TWP 20 RGE 30
<br>
PLAT BOOK A PAGE 200
<br>
BLK 10 LOTS 1.4.5.6.7.8. EX
<br>
POSSIBLY MORE TEXT...
<br>
<hr>
```

**Copy XPath Result for `<href>`:**

```
//*[@id="prc"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center[6]/a
```

**Javascript:**

```
var Xpath = 'substring-after(//*[@id="prc"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center[6]/a, "Description")';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

//Property Description
var result = doc.evaluate(Xpath, doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
Description = result.stringValue;

//Display Message
alert("Description Search Results: " + Description);
```

**Desired Result for Display Message:**

```
SEC 10 TWP 20 RGE 30
PLAT BOOK A PAGE 200
BLK 10 LOTS 1.4.5.6.7.8. EX
POSSIBLY MORE TEXT...
```

Comment: Maybe something like `//*[@id="prc"]/table/tbody/tr/td/br/following::text()`. You may need some post-processing to clean up the resulting strings.

Answer (score 1):

As there are various text nodes XPath 1.0 is not powerful enough to give you a single string result with one expression. Using SaxonJS.XPath you could however use the `string-join` XPath 2.0 and later function:

```js
const html = `<hr>
<center>
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.html" target="_blank">Description</a>
</center>
<br>
SEC 10 TWP 20 RGE 30
<br>
PLAT BOOK A PAGE 200
<br>
BLK 10 LOTS 1.4.5.6.7.8. EX
<br>
POSSIBLY MORE TEXT...
<br>
<hr>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');


alert(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate("string-join(//center[a[. = 'Description']]/following-sibling::text()/normalize-space(), '\n')", doc, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' }))
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```